Debug Rust unit tests using cppvsdbg in VS Code
I'm able to debug a Rust application using cppvsdbg by using specific entries in launch.json. But when debugging single unit tests using the "Debug" link above each unit test function VS Code uses LLDB to debug.
How to use cppvsdbg for these Debug links in VS Code?

I think that's the rust-analyzer.debug.engine setting?

It works: "rust-analyzer.debug.engine": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
